# Is there a relatively simple convolutional neural network architecture for audio denoising?

Tags: python, conv-neural-network, signal-processing

I need to use a CNN for some audio task, and I chose to do something a little more interesting than the obvious audio classifier, so I set out to implement a convolutional denoising autoencoder, but applying a simple image denoising architecture to the task has proven pretty unsuccessful. I'm using Keras on Google Colab with their cloud GPU. I'm using an STFT to represent my audio. Below is my architecture and results (links to spectrograms) so far, any advice?

```
input_layer = Input(shape=X_train[0].shape)
reshaped_input = Reshape([X_train[0].shape[0], X_train[0].shape[1], 1],
                         input_shape=X_train[0].shape)(input_layer)
skip0 = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(reshaped_input)
h = BatchNormalization()(skip0)
h = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(h)

# decoder
h = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(h)
h = BatchNormalization()(h)
h = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(h)
h = add([h, skip0])
h = Conv2D(1, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(h)
output_layer = add([h, reshaped_input])
reshaped_output = Reshape(X_train[0].shape)(output_layer)

autoencoder = Model(input_layer, reshaped_output)
autoencoder.summary()
autoencoder.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam')
```

[Clean Recording](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W51EU.png)
[Noisy Recording (I simply added scaled-down Gaussian noise)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Lxgd.png)
[Prediction](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Px9SS.png)

Comment: I think treating audio spectrogram as an image is interesting but image cleaning is not the same as cleaning up the spectrogram. I think if you can make a training set of noisy spectrogram and clean spectrogram and train your model on these, it might be a better solution. I don't have much experience in ML.

Comment: that's what I've been doing, my Xs are the same as my ys but with some Gaussian noise added to them.

Comment: Did you add the noise to the audio or to STFT? I think you need to add the noise to the audio, if it's not the case.